# CQL: Search a table in cassandra using '<' on a indexed column

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, cql, cassandra-2.0

My cassandra data model:

```
    CREATE TABLE last_activity_tracker ( id uuid, recent_activity_time timestamp, PRIMARY KEY(id));
    CREATE INDEX activity_idx ON last_activity_tracker (recent_activity_time) ;
```

The idea is to keep track of 'id's and their most recent activity of an event.

I need to find the 'id's whose last activity was an year ago.
So, I tried:

```
    SELECT * from last_activity_tracker WHERE recent_activity_time < '2013-12-31' allow filtering;
```

I understand that I cannot use other than '=' for secondary indexed columns.

However, I cannot add 'recent_activity_time' to the key as I need to update this column with the most recent activity time of an event if any.

Any ideas in solving my problem are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can see an issue with your query. You're not hitting a partition. As such, the performance of your query will be quite bad. It'll need to query across your whole cluster (assuming you took measures to make this work).

If you're looking to query the last activity time for an id, think about storing it in a more query friendly format. You might try this:

```
create table tracker (dummy int, day timestamp, id uuid, primary key(dummy, day, id));
```

You can then insert with the day to be the epoch for the date (ignoring the time), and dummy = 0.

That should enable you to do:

```
select * from tracker where dummy=0 and day > '2013-12-31';
```

You can set a ttl on insert so that old entries expire (maybe after a year in this case). The idea is that you're storing information in a way that suits your query.

Comment: This kind of distribution should be absolutely avoided. Creating a "dummy" as partition key will result in all data stored within the same node and replicas. No distribution, big bottleneck, no more horizontal scaling. I know is a "working" solution, but I would not recommend it

Comment: The "dummy" partition key is actually a useful bucketing technique. With a single partition, you give up horizontal scaling. But you can shard across numerous buckets "manually". This is often useful for range queries and lookups. Queries like >, etc. aren't going to work across partitions anyway (and even if you're filtering on the partition key, it's a cluster wide operation).

Comment: Thank you @ashic for the solution. But, as carlo-bertuccini pointed out, all my data would end up on one node and hence is not an ideal solution, as I've lot of 'id's.

Comment: I've decided to store all the activity times in addition to the recent activity time(static) `CREATE TABLE activities ( id uuid, activity_time timestamp, recent_activity_time timestamp static, PRIMARY KEY(id, activity_time));` But, even this didn't work as I couldn't add an index on the static column. Any other ideas to efficiently store all the activity times(need hours, mins and secs) of an id and get all the ids who haven't done an activity since some day. @ashic can you please elaborate on sharding numerous buckets "manually which you mentioned earlier.

Comment: By sharding, here's what I mean: You do some analysis to see what granularity you need, and what level of activity you expect + the number of users. Based on that, and an expected "good" partition size of a few hundred meg, you project how many partitions you'll need. You can then have n "buckets" or partitions with "dummy=0, 1, 2...". When you need to query, you can query all buckets with n queries, and resolve client side. If there's a more natural grouping (like country / locality / group / etc.) then you can use that as the partition key instead of the dummy.

Comment: Your static column approach won't work as each entry will be in a different partition. Even if filtering were possible, it'd be a hit on all partitions. For queries like >, you want to do a query across a single partition, as it's very efficient, and data is sorted along clustering keys. If one partition gives you hotspost, you can use multiple queries (or an IN query on partition keys + range on clustering key) and resolve from there. This is less efficient than hitting a single partition, but it's better than a full cluster query (i.e. ALLOW FILTERING) and let's u go beyond one partition.

Comment: @ashic I tried your initial solution of adding dummy, it doesn't work for me. As I mentioned in the initial question, I need to keep track of JUST the last activity from an id. I need to update any previous activity time with the most recent time for the same id. But, with your suggested approach,I would be storing all the activities. Storing all the activities is fine,but I wouldn't be able to find say the 'id's who haven't done any activity in the last 100 days. Is there any way to get this even with storing  all the events-somehow by ordering the activity times for a given partition key(id)

Comment: you should be able to do select * from tracking where bucket in (0, 1, 2) and date > epoch-for-date. If you have CQL 3.1 access, you can even do the Distinct in the query. You could figure out the epoch for the date to use, or you could store the date as an int (days since Jan 1, 1970 for example). That should enable your query.

Comment: With non-dummy buckets, the query might be like select ... where location in ('london', 'paris', 'italy')....

Comment: Looks like I'm missing something. Say I've two users - user1 has done some activity in last year and this year and user2 has done an actity only in last year. I'm interested in users(ids) who haven't done any activity since last year. With the query  `select  id from tracker where dummy = 0 and day < '2013-12-31' ;` I would be getting id of user1 as well even though user1 has done some activity this year.

Comment: Ah...missed the point :( For users who'se last activity is older than a year, don't think you can do it entirely in cassandra. You might have something monitoring activity events and creating a separate list. Another option is to use something like Spark now that the spark cassandra connector is working nicely.

Comment: I'm able to solve this by making 'recent_activity_time' as clustering key so that I can query with '<'. To keep only the most recent activity, I deleted the row with old activity and then add a one. Seems to work: `CREATE TABLE last_activity_tracker(id uuid,activity_time timestamp, PRIMARY KEY(id, activity_time));
DELETE FROM last_activity_tracker where id = '1'
INSERT INTO last_activity_tracker(id,activity_time)VALUES('1', '2014-08-20')`.I would like to know if cassandra does any delayed delete which may cause a problem by deleting even the newly added column which has same partition key

Comment: To answer your question, a deleted item is marked for deletion and given a grace period. If a node goes down and comes up after the grace period expires, then the "deleted" data will come back. In such a scenario, you need to run a repair. However, cassandra won't delete your newly added data.

Comment: I had to use allow filtering. My query is `select * from last_activity_tracker where activity_time < '2013-12-31' allow filtering;` In order to avoid the risk of deleting the entire row - I'm thinking of doing a select initially to get the previous activity time for an 'id' and then do a delete for the column - id and previous activity and then do an insert. Hoping that this would prevent any deletion of the entire row. @ashic Can you please advise if this better than previous solution - a delete on the row and then an insert.

Comment: The deletes won't be a problem. But be very careful about any query that uses allow filtering in production. These will get slower and slower as your data increases. Allow filtering should be avoided in production as much as possible. If you need aggregation that cassandra can't do out of the box, look to Spark.

Comment: Thank you @ashic I haven't used spark earlier, I'll take a look. I've tried to use cassandra batch - first a delete of row, followed by insert, after this the entire row is deleted. Is this because cassandra does any optimisation and collates all the DMLs to single change and sees that delete row takes precedence over any new inserts? `BEGIN BATCH
DELETE FROM last_activity_tracker where id = '1'
INSERT INTO last_activity_tracker (id, activity_time) VALUES ( '1', '2014-08-21 19:24:20')
APPLY BATCH;`

Comment: You don't need to do the delete at all IMO. All inserts and updates in cassandra are actually upserts on matching primary keys. As such, the update will serve to "replace" the old value.

Comment: @ashic I had to do a delete because, cassandra doesn't allow you to do an update on the column which is part of primary key. Just to remind you, my schem is `CREATE TABLE last_activity_tracker(id uuid,activity_time timestamp, PRIMARY KEY(id, activity_time));` I need to have 'activity_time' as part of the primary key to enable to search on timestamp even with ALLOW FILTERING.